# condition in for loop c++

Tags: c++, stl

I have a function that receives two unsigned long parameters zInit and zFinal and I want to write a for loop from zInit to zFinal including these values.

Currently I am doing so:

```
int delta= (zFinal>=zInit?1:-1);

for (unsigned long k=zInit; k!=zFinal;k+=delta)
{

}
```

The problem is I want to specify the condition "less or equal" or "greater or equal" depending on the comparison between zFinal and zInit, the same as I did with delta. What is a good C++ solution for this? I do not want to write two loops and I do not want to treat the value zFinal separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (unsigned long k=zInit; k*delta <= zFinal*delta; k+=delta)
```

Comment: Fails due to conversion from signed to unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

You have already compared zInit and zFinal; so:

```
for (unsigned long k=zInit; delta > 0 ? k <= zFinal : k >= zFinal ; k += delta)
```

Comment: I like this, although I would say `delta>0` instead of `delta==1` to make it more generic.

Comment: Yes, me too. So modified it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Same solution:

```
for (unsigned long k=zInit; zFinal>=zInit ? k<=zFinal : k>=zFinal ;k+=delta)
```

Comment: Simple and efficient. Thank you!